# How to create a database of phone numbers captured via Twilio/Zapier and how to set up future SMS messages to them

Tags: twilio, zapier

I'm working on a project that starts with people texting a number in Twilio and sending a piece of content. I've connected this step to Zapier and Google Sheets, and all that is working well, but I'm lost on the next 2-3 steps:

1. How to turn a Google Sheets column-full of phone numbers into a textable database
   and
2. How to re-reach out to these numbers (in Twilio?)(in Zapier?)
   and
3. How to set everything up for weekly texts I can customize

Any and all help is appreciated. Been scouring YouTube tutorials but haven't been able to find what I need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This might be a little old and possibly out of date by now, but there is a blog post on [how to send SMS from Google Sheets](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html) that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer (the question can't actually be answered objectively, as it's very broad and opinion-seeking). Also, please note that link-only answers are highly discouraged (and are typically removed fairly fast) - another argument for dropping the link into a comment instead.

Comment: I agree that the question is too broad, and in this case thought that the best way to help was to point to a tutorial. I know link-only answers are discouraged, but in this case I deemed it to be the most helpful thing I could do and therefore worthy of being an answer and not a comment.